# MapR maprcli command not found

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I have installed mapr-client，mapr-httpfs and also I have run the command below:

```
./configure.sh -N my.cluster.com -c -secure -C 192.168.145.121:7222 -HS 192.168.145.122
```

and the result is:

```
create /opt/mapr/conf/conf.old
Configuring Hadoop-2.7.0 at /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0
Done configuring Hadoop
CLDB node list: 192.168.145.121:7222
Zookeeper node list: 
External Zookeeper node list:
```

But when I run maprcli command it fails:

```
command: maprcli node services -name httpfs -action restart -nodes  192.168.145.121 192.168.145.122
result warn:-bash: maprcli: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

The maprcli command is not included in the mapr-client library.  If you need maprcli, you should install the mapr-core package.